# Is it bad to call shell commands from Java?

Tags: java, shell, bloom-filter

I need to use set difference of two files in Java. Files have around 50 Million lines each, So I can't load them in memory completely. I could do that phases but I am planning to use `comm` command from linux which efficiently does so.

1. Is there a library in java to efficiently do the job?
2. Is it bad design to call shell commands from a program?

**Details**

I have file1 and file2 each having over 40 million lines. I don't want to fit them in memory. I need to find the set difference of file1 - file2. i.e. Lines which are in file1 but not in file2. In general I would following algo:

```
 1. Read file1 line by line and save it in HashSet.
 2. Read file2 line by line.
 3. Remove each line of file2 from Hashset if present
```

Is there any way I could do this without saving file1 in Hashset.

**Edit: My Solution**

I have finally decided to use bloom to solve the purpose. I know that bloom filter give approximate answer but I have taken the bitset length to be long enough *(14*size of file1 i.e. 10Million)* which gives me an accuracy of 10^-9. Following is the algo

```
 1. Read each line of file2 and add to Bloom Filter.
 2. Now, file2 is compressed from 300MB+ to 40MB+
 3. Read each line of file1, if not present in filter print the line
```

Comment: Without more context, this question is off topic because it asks for external library or primarily opinion based answers

Comment: I am editing the question.

Answer (score 4):

Using a shell script would add extra dependencies to your application, also it may make your application platform-dependent. E.g. on OS without `comm`.

Have you tried `InputStream` to process the files? It won't load the whole content in memory. If `comm` does what you need, it means, you just want to do line by line diff, you can give `InputStream` a try.

side note, if you are about to use `comm`, you should make sure, your files are already sorted.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However I don't understand how this will help. I need set difference i.e. All the lines which are in file1 but not in file2.
One way I could think is to 'read a chunk of file1 in Hashset' compare with each line of file2. Repeat it for all the chunks of file1

I was actually planning to use 'sort|comm -12'

Comment: @MangatRaiModi `comm` compare files line by line. If you want to do the same, you could try `InputStream`. You read two files in parallel, compare line by line, if diff found, output/save .. otherwise do nothing.  The worst case is, the two files are completely different, then you need to think about how to store the comparison result.

Comment: But that  wouldn't work if the files are not sorted like?

Comment: @MangatRaiModi I don't know your requirement. sort big file is another problem. do some google, you will find answers.

Comment: Thank you for the help. However I have decided to use bloom filter.

Answer (score 0):

1.You can call a cmd command with a ProccessBuilder object
2.In my opinion there are more efficient ways(Batch files e.t.c)